# React App on AWS S3/Cloudfront does not load JS content

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I tried finding a solution for almost 8 hours and I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong.
I hosted an app on AWS S3 with Cloudfront and only the index.html page loads, all the JS/routing code does not.

These are the CloudFront settings:
[image]

This is the error I get if I try to go to a route that's not the index:[image]

Which makes me think the JS code is not being executed at all.

Does someone have any idea what's going on? Everything works besides this thing. It's like, it loads the main index.html page and that's it.

This is the `index.js` file (not showing you the imports but they're there of course):

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <HashRouter>
      <App />
    </HashRouter>
  </QueryClientProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: In this guide there are all the neccessery step you should take -  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the problem. Answering here just in case someone stumbles into the same problem in the future.

The console was logging an error coming from the JS script. Weirdly enough, I did not have that error during npm build (module.exports is not defined).

So I fixed the error and tried again and the app finally loaded as it should.

Comment: You could maybe add in some more information about what the error was, and what you did to fix the error if you ant to respond to your own question, or else it really isn't doing much good for others who may not know how to fix it.

Comment: Was just importing a JavaScript function which had "module.exports = *functionname*". I realized I wasn't even using that function so I deleted it and removed the import and that solved the problem. Of course, I didn't solve the root problem but got around it.

 The important lesson to understand is that if the React components are not loading, chances are there's an error somewhere in the script and the console will log it. I did not see this problem mentioned anywhere when I was looking for a solution, plus npm build did not log any error. I initially thought it had to do with AWS.